# Android : Schedule SMS at Alarm Manager

Tags: android

I am writing app to schedule SMS from alarm Manager. It works for me only one time and second time onwards it generate the multiple SMS.

Times are saved in SQL LITE and after send a SMS from Broadcast receiver read the DB and set the next alarm.

if 1 SMS has sent, second time it sends 2 SMS. next time 3 sms, and so on.  I am using AmarmManager array and PendingIntents array to set alarm.

here is my coding... Please elp me... i am spending fer day for this taks..

```
public void SetAlarm(MessageInfo info, long delay, int amcount)
{

    try
    {
        AlarmMSGInfo = info;
        SaveMSGINFOPreference();

        //Save Sent Status to Preference..
        //savePreferences("SENT", old);
        // register the alarm broadcast here
        AMCount = amcount;
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.rememberme.rm") );
        //pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent("com.techblogon.alarmexample"),0 );

        pendingIntent[amcount] = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( RememberMe.this,amcount, new Intent("com.rememberme.rm"),PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT );
        alarmManager[amcount] = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));
        alarmManager[amcount].set( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, delay , pendingIntent[amcount] );
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Toast.makeText(RememberMe.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(RememberMe.this, "Alarm cannot be set...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

This is my Broadcast receiver ..

private void RegisterAlarmBroadcast()
    {

```
    //This is the call back function(BroadcastReceiver) which will be call when your 
    //alarm time will reached.
    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {

        private static final String TAG = "Alarm Example Receiver";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {

                String s = intent.getAction().toString();
                if(intent.getAction() != null )
                {
                Log.i(TAG,"BroadcastReceiver::OnReceive() >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
                //Toast.makeText(context, "Congrats!. Your Alarm time has been reached", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                MessageInfo temp= LoadMSGINFOPreference();

                if(temp == null )
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    String snt = loadSavedPreferences("SENT");
                    if(snt== "")
                        Sent = 0;
                    else
                        Sent = Integer.valueOf(snt);

                    int status = 0;
                    if(Sent == 0)
                    {
                        //MessageInfo SentInfo = dbHandler.Get_MessageInfo(Sent);
                        //status = SentInfo.getStatus();
                        //}
                        //Toast.makeText(RememberMe.this, String.valueOf(msgType) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //if(status == 0) 
                        //{
                            if(temp.getMSGType() == 1)
                            {
                                _Recipients = ReadPhoneNumbers(temp.getRecipients());
                                _Message = temp.getMessage();
                                for(String number:_Recipients)
                                {
                                    try 
                                    {
                                        String num = number;
                                        //Toast.makeText(context, "Congrats!. Your Alarm time has been reached : " + num + ":", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                         sendSMS(num, _Message); 
                                      } 
                                    catch (Exception e) 
                                    {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SMS faild, please try again later!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                      }                                     
                                }
                                alarmManager[AMCount].cancel(pendingIntent[AMCount]);
                            }

                            //Updaate te record to set status = 1...(SEND)
                            temp.setStatus(1);
                            dbHandler.Update_MessageInfo(temp);
                            savePreferences("SENT", String.valueOf(temp.getID()));
                            //take nearest Record from da DB.
                            MessageInfo minfo = new MessageInfo();
                            ArrayList<MessageInfo> msgInfo_array_from_db = dbHandler.Get_MessageInfos();
                            if(msgInfo_array_from_db.size() > 0)
                            {
                                minfo = GetLatestMSGInfo(msgInfo_array_from_db);
                                //Set tat record to alarm manager...
                                SetAlarm(minfo, minfo.getDelay(), temp.getID());
                            }
                        //}

                    }
        }

    };
}
private void SaveMSGINFOPreference()
{
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor prefsEditor = sp.edit();
     Gson gson = new Gson();
     String json = gson.toJson(AlarmMSGInfo);
     prefsEditor.putString("AlarmMSGInfo", json);
     prefsEditor.commit();
}
```

Comment: Does this repetition happen for 15-20 mins after 1st SMS was triggered.?

Comment: Vaibs! Yes. Its happening. IF sent number of SMS is 3 then next time it sends 4 SMS.

Comment: Is your setAlarm method getting called repeatedly.?

Comment: Yes. SetAlarm metod called repeatedly from RegisterAlarmBroadcast() method. Because once SMS sent next alarm should set from this. other wise dont have place to get next SMS.

Comment: I have post my SaveMSGINFOPreference() as well. Please help me to get out of this.

Comment: @sunethrajamanthri: Why dint you use setRepeating() for AlarmManager?

Comment: Vaibs : The thing is, Scheduled SMS are not in regular intervals. They may be vary. If one sent at 1.30pm and next may be at any time. Can I do this using SETREPEAT????

Comment: Mike: Thank u.. i will try with dis.. Can you please suggest me a way to achieve this task. (Scheduling SMS)

Comment: Mike : Still same thing happening.

Comment: I know that this is not technical issue. This is the problem of programming. But still i could not fix this issue. Since 3 days im working on this. I did implement this different ways but one of them was not succeeded.